# React, Redux: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'region')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am fetching data (an object) into a redux state and showing into textarea when user clicks on edit:

```
const regionData = useSelector((state) => state.myReducer.userDetailList.region);
```

but first time it gives me below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'region')
```

also this error occurred when i changed code as per eslint suggestion:

```
i.e. 
Use an object spread instead of `Object.assign` eg: `{ ...foo }`
```

Old Code:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    userDetailList: {
        region: action.userDetailsPayload.region,
    },
});
```

New Code:

```
 const userDetailList = {
     region: action.userDetailsPayload.region,
 };

 return { ...state, ...userDetailList };
```

As a result userDetailList showing as BLANK in Chrome redux-devtool. its working with old code (Object.assign)

I am new to react and redux, so any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a promblem same this one.
Finally I've found out that if I use term "Reducer" or "State" at the end of state's name or reducer's name that are witten by me,
[my code runs with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6uhc.png)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'result_201')

my reducer:

```
    export function netInfoRecordReducer (
    state = initialStateNetInfoRecord,
    action : Actions
  ) : NetInfoRecordState {
    switch (action.type) {
      case SET_NET_INFO_RECORD: {
        if ( action.payload.RESULT === "SUCCESS") {
          return {
            ...state,
            result_201: action.payload.RESULT_CONTENT,
          };
        }
        return state;
      }
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

and my index.tsx file for defining CobineReducer and RoutState:

```
export default combineReducers({
  netInfoRecordReducer: netInfoRecordReducer,
});

export interface RootState {
  netInfoRecordState: NetInfoRecordState;
}
```

it runs with that error when I want acceess to the state in another file:

```
    const netInfoRecord = useAppSelector( (state) => 
        state.netInfoRecord.result_201);
    console.log(netInfoRecord);
```

but if I remove "State" and "Reducer" term and change my index.tsx file to :

```
    export default combineReducers({
      netInfoRecord: netInfoRecordReducer,
    });

    export interface RootState {
     netInfoRecord: NetInfoRecordState;
    }
```

it works now !  :)